# JPA Criteria API: order by the number of child entities in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I have 2 entities: Faculty and Course which are in a one-to-many relationship, that is - a Faculty can offer multiple courses, but it can also offer none.

I'm trying to sort the faculties by the number of courses they offer, doing this:

```
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(criteriaBuilder.size(root.get(Faculty_.courses))));
```

The problem is that it fails on

```
criteriaBuilder.size(root.get(Faculty_.courses))
```

with a NullPointerException because Faculty_.courses is null for certain faculties. 
Please help me write this in a better way so that it takes into consideration the case when courses is null.

Note: I have to use JPA Criteria API because this is part of a larger query with pagination and stuff. So writing it using query language is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write Faculty in a way that it always has a list (or set) or courses, which is empty instead of `null` if there are none:

```
@OneToMany
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Highly appreciated. But apparently I got the source of the problem wrong. Null pointer was being thrown because I had SetAttribute<Faculty, Course> in my StaticMetamodel instead of ListAttribute. After I changed this it worked. It seems that Criteria API takes care of the null cases itself. Cheers

Comment: Ok, even better. But the empty set version is also easier to use if a Faculty is used directly. About that static metamodel issues: If you can, you should generate it automatically to avoid such issues. Have a look at http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/jpamodelgen.html if you don't know it.